# SwiftUi- Cannot convert value of type Binding<[ExercisePlan]>.Element to expected argument type Binding<[ExercisePlan]>

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to create a NavigationLink to another view (ExercisePlanDetailView) and it requires me to pass the @State var exercisePlan as a binding var but it keeps giving me this error. I have a @Binding var inside the ExercisePlan Detail view too.

ExercisePlanView:

`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExercisePlanView: View {
    
    @State var isSheetPresented = false
    @State var exercisePlan = [
        ExercisePlan(title: "Exercise Plan 1", details: "Choose this for a light and basic workout", exercise:
        Exercise(title: "Toe touches and Arm Stretches", duration: 5), exercise2: Exercise(title: "ArmCircles", duration: 5), exercise3: Exercise(title: "Calf Raises", duration: 5), exercise4: Exercise(title: "Jog on the Spot", duration: 5)
        ),
        ExercisePlan(title: "Exercise Plan 2", details: "Choose this for a medium difficulty workout", exercise: Exercise(title: "High Knee March", duration: 5), exercise2: Exercise(title: "Stair Exercise", duration: 10), exercise3: Exercise(title: "Chair Exercise", duration: 5), exercise4: Exercise(title: "Lunges", duration: 5)),
//        ExercisePlan(title: "Exercise Plan 2", details: "Choose this plan for a more intermediate set of workouts", exercise: Exercise(title: "Wall Push-ups", duration: <#T##Int#>), exercise2: <#T##Exercise#>, exercise3: <#T##Exercise#>, exercise4: <#T##Exercise#>)
   ]

    var body: some View {
        
        let row = GridItem(.fixed(50), spacing: 20, alignment: .center)
        
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHGrid(rows: [row]) {
                    ForEach($exercisePlan) { $exercisePlan in
                        NavigationLink {
                            ExercisePlanDetailView(exercisePlan: $exercisePlan)
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        } label: {
                            Text(exercisePlan.title)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .frame(width: 120, height: 130)
                                .padding()
                                .background((Color(red: 220/255, green: 247/255, blue: 99/255)))
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                        }
                        
                    }
//                    .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) {
//                        ExercisePlanDetailView(exercisePlan: $exercisePlan)
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
        

        struct ExercisePlanView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
            static var previews: some View {
                ExercisePlanView()
            }
        }
```

`

ExercisePlanDetailView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExercisePlanDetailView: View {
    @Binding var exercisePlan: [ExercisePlan]
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text($exercisePlan.title)
            }
        }
    }
    

struct ExercisePlanDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExercisePlanDetailView(exercisePlan: .constant([]))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach, where you pass only the desired exercisePlan
to the details view, not the whole array:

In `ExercisePlanView`

```
ForEach($exercisePlan) { $plan in
//..
ExercisePlanDetailView(exercisePlan: $plan)
//...
```

In `ExercisePlanDetailView`

```
@Binding var exercisePlan: ExercisePlan
 //...
 Text(exercisePlan.title)
 //...
```

And in the `ExercisePlanDetailView_Previews`

```
  ExercisePlanDetailView(exercisePlan:.constant(ExercisePlan(title:....)))
```